# how to show svg graph in vue with only svg graph link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

the only thing I have now is a svg link, opening the link on the browser will show up a svg graph.

I want to show up a svg graph in vue application, http://tiku.qycareer.com/api/captcha/index?1661672036108

I tried this way in vue but doesn't work.

any other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

You can load any external file, **and inline it**, with the `<load-file>` (native javascript) Web Component.

Loads of options, unlicensed and only 8 lines of code:
[Dev.To blog post <load-file> Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

```html
<script src="https://load-file.github.io/element.js"></script>
 
<load-file src="http://tiku.qycareer.com/api/captcha/index?1661672036108"></load-file>

<style>
  svg{ background:lightgreen }
  rect { stroke:green; stroke-width:60; rx:60 }
</style>
```